# bash script nested loop of input file (csv) to create xml elements with varying numbers of attributes

Tags: xml, bash

I am new to bash scripting and am trying to generate an xml document from a csv data file.  The sample data file I am working with contains 3 (may have hundreds) unique elements (expression column) with 5 attributes for each element. I have a nested loop but cannot get the 2nd loop to complete the 5 attributes before returning to first loop.

my sample data file is this:

```
source,attribute,type,expression,confidence
profile_sysObjectID,FastIron ,Model,^.?1\.3\.6\.1\.4\.1\.1991\.1\.3\.1,92

profile_sysObjectID,Switch/Router,DeviceType,^.?1\.3\.6\.1\.4\.1\.1991\.1\.3\.1,90

profile_sysObjectID,Brocade,Vendor,^.?1\.3\.6\.1\.4\.1\.1991\.1\.3\.1,90

profile_sysObjectID,Embedded (Brocade),OS,^.?1\.3\.6\.1\.4\.1\.1991\.1\.3\.1,90

profile_sysObjectID,Embedded (Brocade),Version,^.?
1\.3\.6\.1\.4\.1\.1991\.1\.3\.1,90

profile_sysObjectID,FastIron WG Switch,Model,^.?
1\.3\.6\.1\.4\.1\.1991\.1\.3\.1\.1,92

profile_sysObjectID,Switch,DeviceType,^.?1\.3\.6\.1\.4\.1\.1991\.1\.3\.1\.1,92

profile_sysObjectID,Brocade,Vendor,^.?1\.3\.6\.1\.4\.1\.1991\.1\.3\.1\.1,92

profile_sysObjectID,Embedded (Brocade),OS,^.?
1\.3\.6\.1\.4\.1\.1991\.1\.3\.1\.1,92

profile_sysObjectID,Embedded (Brocade),Version,^.?
1\.3\.6\.1\.4\.1\.1991\.1\.3\.1\.1,92

profile_sysObjectID,FastIron BB Switch,Model,^.?
1\.3\.6\.1\.4\.1\.1991\.1\.3\.1\.2,92

profile_sysObjectID,Switch,DeviceType,^.?1\.3\.6\.1\.4\.1\.1991\.1\.3\.1\.2,92

profile_sysObjectID,Brocade,Vendor,^.?1\.3\.6\.1\.4\.1\.1991\.1\.3\.1\.2,92

profile_sysObjectID,Embedded (Brocade),OS,^.?
1\.3\.6\.1\.4\.1\.1991\.1\.3\.1\.2,92

profile_sysObjectID,Embedded (Brocade),Version,^.?
1\.3\.6\.1\.4\.1\.1991\.1\.3\.1\.2,92
```

---

My current script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo '   input filename...'
read file_in
file_out="sampleout.xml"
echo '<patterns xmlns="urn:lumeta:pattern:6.0" version="2.1.666" user-
provided="true">' > $file_out
while IFS=$',' read -r -a arry
do
  echo '  <pattern>' >> $file_out
  echo '    <source>'${arry[0]}'</source>' >> $file_out
  echo '    <expression>'${arry[3]}'</expression>' >> $file_out
  echo '    <attributes>' >> $file_out
        exp=${arry[3]}
        for exp in ${arry[3]}
        do
  echo '        <attribute> type="'${arry[2]}'" 
confidence="'${arry[4]}'">'${arry[1]}'</attribute>' >> $file_out
        done
  echo '  </pattern>' >> $file_out
done < $file_in
echo  '</patterns>' >> $file_out
exit 0
```

My current XML output from this script sub-loops only the first attribute of the parent element before returning to first loop to create a new element.
Current output is:

```
<patterns xmlns="urn:lumeta:pattern:6.0" version="2.1.666" user-provided="true">
  <pattern>
    <source>profile_sysObjectID</source>
    <expression>^.?1\.3\.6\.1\.4\.1\.1991\.1\.3\.1</expression>
    <attributes>
        <attribute> type="Model" confidence="92">FastIron </attribute>
  </pattern>
  <pattern>
    <source>profile_sysObjectID</source>
    <expression>^.?1\.3\.6\.1\.4\.1\.1991\.1\.3\.1</expression>
    <attributes>
        <attribute> type="DeviceType" confidence="90">Switch/Router</attribute>
  </pattern>
  <pattern>
    <source>profile_sysObjectID</source>
    <expression>^.?1\.3\.6\.1\.4\.1\.1991\.1\.3\.1</expression>
    <attributes>
        <attribute> type="Vendor" confidence="90">Brocade</attribute>
  </pattern>
  <pattern>
    <source>profile_sysObjectID</source>
    <expression>^.?1\.3\.6\.1\.4\.1\.1991\.1\.3\.1</expression>
    <attributes>
        <attribute> type="OS" confidence="90">Embedded (Brocade)</attribute>
  </pattern>
  <pattern>
    <source>profile_sysObjectID</source>
    <expression>^.?1\.3\.6\.1\.4\.1\.1991\.1\.3\.1</expression>
    <attributes>
        <attribute> type="Version" confidence="90">Embedded (Brocade)</attribute>
  </pattern>
  <pattern>
    <source>profile_sysObjectID</source>
    <expression>^.?1\.3\.6\.1\.4\.1\.1991\.1\.3\.1\.1</expression>
    <attributes>
        <attribute> type="Model" confidence="92">FastIron WG Switch</attribute>
  </pattern>
  <pattern>
    <source>profile_sysObjectID</source>
    <expression>^.?1\.3\.6\.1\.4\.1\.1991\.1\.3\.1\.1</expression>
    <attributes>
        <attribute> type="DeviceType" confidence="92">Switch</attribute>
  </pattern>
  <pattern>
    <source>profile_sysObjectID</source>
    <expression>^.?1\.3\.6\.1\.4\.1\.1991\.1\.3\.1\.1</expression>
    <attributes>
        <attribute> type="Vendor" confidence="92">Brocade</attribute>
  </pattern>
  <pattern>
    <source>profile_sysObjectID</source>
    <expression>^.?1\.3\.6\.1\.4\.1\.1991\.1\.3\.1\.1</expression>
    <attributes>
        <attribute> type="OS" confidence="92">Embedded (Brocade)</attribute>
  </pattern>
  <pattern>
    <source>profile_sysObjectID</source>
    <expression>^.?1\.3\.6\.1\.4\.1\.1991\.1\.3\.1\.1</expression>
    <attributes>
        <attribute> type="Version" confidence="92">Embedded (Brocade)</attribute>
  </pattern>
```

The desired output for the first element above would be this:

```
<patterns xmlns="urn:lumeta:pattern:6.0" version="2.1.666" user-provided="true">
  <pattern>
    <source>profile_sysObjectID</source>
    <expression>^.?1\.3\.6\.1\.4\.1\.1991\.1\.3\.1</expression>
    <attributes>
        <attribute type="Model" confidence="92">FastIron </attribute>
        <attribute type="DeviceType" confidence="90">Switch/Router</attribute>
        <attribute type="Vendor" confidence="90">Brocade</attribute>
        <attribute type="OS" confidence="90">Embedded (Brocade)</attribute>
        <attribute type="Version" confidence="90">Embedded (Brocade)</attribute>
    </attributes>
  </pattern>
  <pattern>
    <source>profile_sysObjectID</source>
    <expression>^.?1\.3\.6\.1\.4\.1\.1991\.1\.3\.1\.1</expression>
    <attributes>
        <attribute type="Model" confidence="92">FastIron WG Switch</attribute>
        <attribute type="DeviceType" confidence="92">Switch</attribute>
        <attribute type="Vendor" confidence="92">Brocade</attribute>
        <attribute type="OS" confidence="92">Embedded (Brocade)</attribute>
        <attribute type="Version" confidence="92">Embedded (Brocade)</attribute>
    </attributes>
  </pattern>
</patterns>
```

Answer (score 1):

I edited your desired output in order to make it well-formed XML.
I did your homework with a lot of bash-isms. Please note that I wouldn’t use this in production without adding some error-checking code. There are no comments, but with a bit of RTFD everything will be clear enough.

```
#!/bin/bash

function read_line () {
    declare -g $vars
    IFS=, read $vars || break
}

function tag_open () {
    declare -g indent
    echo "${indent}<${1}${2:+ }$2>"
    indent+='  '
}

function tag_close () {
    indent="${indent%  }"
    echo "${indent}</$1>"
}

function print_tagged_var () {
    echo "$indent<${1}${2:+ }$2>${!1}</$1>"
}

function print_attribute () {
    local props
    printf -v props 'type="%s" confidence="%u"' "$type" "$confidence"
    print_tagged_var attribute "$props"
}

function consume_pattern () {
    read_line
    tag_open pattern
        print_tagged_var source
        print_tagged_var expression
        tag_open attributes
            print_attribute
            for i in {1..4}; do
                read_line
                print_attribute
            done
        tag_close attributes
    tag_close pattern
}


##### MAIN LOOP #####

read vars
vars="${vars//,/ }"
tag_open patterns 'xmlns="urn:lumeta:pattern:6.0" version="2.1.666" user-provided="true"'
    while :; do
        consume_pattern
    done
tag_close patterns
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you for setting me in the right direction. I have spent the last couple hours RTFD'ing your code and I'm getting there.